# Download Web Page with JSON in order?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get all of the currency rates from this website and processing it in my app.
This is the website: https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json

I am using this class to get all of the currency rates, but the problem is that it is getting it in a random order because of Iterator keys = ratesObj.key();

How do I fix this so that it gets all of the currency rates in order?

This is the code:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Double>>
{
    protected ArrayList<Double> doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        ArrayList<Double> response = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (String url : urls)
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try
            {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(content);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                while (isr.read(buffer) != -1)
                {
                    sb.append(buffer);
                }
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONObject ratesObj = jobj.getJSONObject("rates");
                Iterator<String> keys = ratesObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext())
                {
                    response.add(Double.parseDouble(ratesObj.getString(keys.next())));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Double> result)
    { 
        currency_values = result;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help! I really appreciate it.

*UPDATE*: This is the code now.

```
try
            {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                String s = EntityUtils.toString(execute.getEntity());
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject ratesObj = jobj.getJSONObject("rates");
                Iterator<String> keys = ratesObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext())
                {
                    response.add(Double.parseDouble(ratesObj.getString(keys.next())));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `InputStreamReader` and `StringBuilder` when there's `EntityUtils.toString(execute.getEntity())` which obeys the content encoding set by the server, is much less code and has proper error handling.

Comment: Then this would change the loop below it. How would I fix the loop then?

Comment: If you mean the `while (isr.read(buffer) != -1)` loop, it would not be changed -- you would remove it completely, as it's no longer necessary if you use `EntityUtils.toString()`.

Comment: What do you intend to do with just the doubles that relies on the correct ordering? Why not use a `Map<String, Double>` mapping currency code to exchange rate and not care about the ordering at all?

Comment: Philipp, I understand what you mean. I did it separately, but your solution seems to make more sense. However, I tried your method, but now I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException. This is what the code looks like:

Comment: You should remove the line that reads `InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();`, too.

Comment: I did, however it still does not work. It runs, it just outputs the wrong answer.

Comment: My advice to use `EntityUtils` had nothing to do with preserving the order of exchange rates, just cleaner code. For that, see the 4th comment.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to use Map<String, Double>? I understand why its more efficient and easier to implement, but it would be greatly appreciated if there was an example I could look at. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer below where I tried to put everything from my comments together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to implement what I suggested in the comments, using a `SortedMap<String, Double>` to map the three-letter currency codes to exchange rates while keeping it alphabetically ordered by currency code:

```
  protected SortedMap<String, Double> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    SortedMap<String, Double> result = new TreeMap<String, Double>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    for (String url : urls) {
      try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject rates = json.getJSONObject("rates");
        Iterator<String> currencyCodes = rates.keys();
        while (currencyCodes.hasNext()) {
          String currencyCode = currencyCodes.next();
          double rate = rates.getDouble(currencyCode);
          result.put(currencyCode, rate);
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to download exchange rates from " + url, ex);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it does work. Thank you so much for helping a young programmer like me. I appreciate it!